# Scrapy crawl spider does not follow all the links and does not populate Item loader

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy

I am trying to take the links for this website (https://minerals.usgs.gov/science/mineral-deposit-database/#products) and scrape the title from each one. However it doen't work! The spider does not seem to follow the links!

**CODE**

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
import datetime
import socket
from depositsusa.items import DepositsusaItem
from scrapy.loader import ItemLoader


class DepositsSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'deposits'
    allowed_domains = ['web']
    start_urls = ['https://minerals.usgs.gov/science/mineral-deposit- 
    database/#products', ]

    rules = (
    Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths='//*[@id="products"][1]/p/a'),
         callback='parse'),
    )

    def parse(self, response):
        i = ItemLoader(item=DepositsusaItem(), response=response)
        i.add_xpath('name', '//*[@class="container"][1]/header/h1/text()')
        i.add_value('url', response.url)
        i.add_value('project', self.settings.get('BOT_NAME'))
        i.add_value('spider', self.name)
        i.add_value('server', socket.gethostname())
        i.add_value('date', datetime.datetime.now())
        return i.load_item()
```

**items**

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.item import Item, Field


class DepositsusaItem(Item):
    # main fields
    name = Field()
    # Housekeeping Fields
    url = Field()
    project = Field()
    spider = Field()
    server = Field()
    date = Field()
    pass
```

**OUTPUT**

```
(base) C:\Users\User\Documents\Python WebCrawling Learing 
Projects\depositsusa>scrapy crawl deposits
2018-11-17 00:29:48 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 1.5.1 started (bot: 
depositsusa)
2018-11-17 00:29:48 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Versions: lxml 4.2.5.0, libxml2 
2.9.8, cssselect 1.0.3, parsel 1.4.0, w3lib 1.19.0, Twisted 18.7.0, Python 
3.7.0 (default, Jun 28 2018, 08:04:48) [MSC v.1912 64 bit (AMD64)], 
pyOpenSSL 18.0.0 (OpenSSL 1.0.2p  14 Aug 2018), cryptography 2.3.1, Platform 
Windows-10-10.0.17134-SP0
2018-11-17 00:29:48 [scrapy.crawler] INFO: Overridden settings: {'BOT_NAME': 
'depositsusa', 'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'depositsusa.spiders', 'ROBOTSTXT_OBEY': 
True, 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['depositsusa.spiders']}
2018-11-17 00:29:48 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled extensions:
['scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats',
'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole',
'scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats']
2018-11-17 00:29:48 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled downloader 
middlewares:
['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.robotstxt.RobotsTxtMiddleware',
'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware',
'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware',
'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware',
'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware',
'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware',
'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies.CookiesMiddleware',
'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware',
'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats']
2018-11-17 00:29:48 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:
['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',
'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',
'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',
'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',
'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware']
2018-11-17 00:29:48 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
[]
2018-11-17 00:29:48 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2018-11-17 00:29:48 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 
pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2018-11-17 00:29:48 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] DEBUG: Telnet console 
listening on 127.0.0.1:6024
2018-11-17 00:29:49 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET 
https://minerals.usgs.gov/robots.txt> (referer: None)
2018-11-17 00:29:49 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET 
https://minerals.usgs.gov/science/mineral-deposit-database/#products> 
(referer: None)
2018-11-17 00:29:49 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 
https://minerals.usgs.gov/science/mineral-deposit-database/>
{'date': [datetime.datetime(2018, 11, 17, 0, 29, 49, 832526)],
'project': ['depositsusa'],
'server': ['DESKTOP-9CUE746'],
'spider': ['deposits'],
'url': ['https://minerals.usgs.gov/science/mineral-deposit-database/']}
2018-11-17 00:29:49 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2018-11-17 00:29:49 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 475,
'downloader/request_count': 2,
'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 2,
'downloader/response_bytes': 25123,
'downloader/response_count': 2,
'downloader/response_status_count/200': 2,
'finish_reason': 'finished',
'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2018, 11, 16, 23, 29, 49, 848053),
'item_scraped_count': 1,
'log_count/DEBUG': 4,
'log_count/INFO': 7,
'response_received_count': 2,
'scheduler/dequeued': 1,
'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 1,
'scheduler/enqueued': 1,
'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 1,
'start_time': datetime.datetime(2018, 11, 16, 23, 29, 48, 520273)}
2018-11-17 00:29:49 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

I am quite new at python, so what seems to be the problem? Is it something to do with linkextraction or the parse function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change a couple of things.

First, when you use a `CrawlSpider`, you can't have a callback named `parse` as you would override the `CrawlSpider`'s `parse`: https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#crawling-rules

[image: warning]

Secondly, you want to have the correct list of `allowed_domains`.

Try something like this:

```
class DepositsSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'deposits'
    allowed_domains = ['doi.org']
    start_urls = ['https://minerals.usgs.gov/science/mineral-deposit-database/#products', ]

    rules = (
    Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths='//*[@id="products"][1]/p/a'),
         callback='parse_x'),
    )

    def parse_x(self, response):
        i = ItemLoader(item=DepositsusaItem(), response=response)
        i.add_xpath('name', '//*[@class="container"][1]/header/h1/text()')
        i.add_value('url', response.url)
        i.add_value('project', self.settings.get('BOT_NAME'))
        i.add_value('spider', self.name)
        i.add_value('server', socket.gethostname())
        i.add_value('date', datetime.datetime.now())
        return i.load_item()
```